# IIS Rewrite rule to edit content outgoing to proxy a HTTP image file?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to figure out what I would need to do for a rewrite rule to apply to  tags if possible to append to the source to basically proxy the content of HTTP links.

Looks like google does it for its webmail and I need something similar for my self hosted webmail. I could ingore the Not Fully Secure warning but I want to try to finish it.

Unfortunately I dont remember how I did it in the past and I deleted the old folder to look at the web.config file that would have been in there.

This way I could look for image links with an image of http://example.com/image.png and make it https://example.org/proxy.php?url=http://example.com/image.png and then it would load the same image but now be secure. I have the php setup as needed to do this but now I need to figure out this outbound rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rules like this.

```
<rule name="rule" preCondition="ISHTML">
    <match filterByTags="A, Img" pattern="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="https://example.org/proxy.php?url=http://{HTTP_HOST}{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

According to the law of image name and php page name, you can customize regular expressions to match the image you want to rewrite and the rewritten url

Comment: Unless the ISHTML is defined differently than from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module

The page now gives an HTTP 500 error going to it with the rule on.

Comment: Also I did update the link and such to my needs. But im not sure why it might be giving that error off hand.

Comment: The issue was determined to be caused by compression. Now I just need to find out why its failing on what looks like tabled images.